# Can Dexie syncable be used with an api server vs directly with a database

Tags: dexie, dreamfactory

I have seen the sample projects on your [website](http://dexie.org/) for [Dexie.Syncable](http://dexie.org/docs/Syncable/Dexie.Syncable.js.html) such as sync-server and sync-client and they all seem to write to a datbase directly vs interacting with a web api.  I am looking for a little help in where to get started beyond the examples on the website.  The api I am trying to write a gateway for is [dreamfactory](https://www.dreamfactory.com/)

Also it looks like version 2 beta has had many improvements to Dexie.Syncable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to build a new server-project based on either [WebSocketSyncServer.js](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/blob/master/samples/remote-sync/websocket/WebSocketSyncServer.js) or [the github repo of sync-server](https://github.com/nponiros/sync_server). However, I cannot give the details on how to call REST APIs instead of working directly towards database or memory. I would suggest using ES2016 async/await since your API calls are asynchronic.

Maybe you could try getting more help on https://github.com/nponiros/sync_server by filing an issue there.

Comment: That is what I am doing I have your example sync client/server adn have added a new database adapter that pushes dreamfactory.  Thanks for your help